# Ionic 4 side menu full screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

create a **full screen ionic side menu** in ionic 4

I want a create ionic 4 side menu in full screen Like this Image

[image: I want a create ionic 4 side menu in full screen Like this Image]
Image below :-

> I want a create ionic 4 side menu in full screen Like this Image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the CSS custom property to show it fullscreen

```
ion-menu {
    --min-width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Modal from the ModalController to do this fullpage Things:
See how it will look with preview in the API v3:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Use for your ionic4 for the new API:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal-controller

you just need to add another Component and load it via the Modal Controller.